# Notifications for Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am looking to implement notifications on my app. The way I would like for this to work is when I put something on my website, that is connected to my app, it gives a notification automatically even if the app is not running.  I am just looking for the easiest way to accomplish this. By the way the info that is added from the website is put into a listview in the app(if that helps at all).

Comment: Sounds to me like an RSS feed might work.  You'll need some kind of app or service running on the mobile device.  Otherwise, how will it know?

Answer (score 2):

The server needs to do a several things in order to talk GCM:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

The client needs to do some registration and let your server know of the GCM registration ID:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Those links will provide much more detail though

Answer (score -1):

Your app may poll your side every N minutes/hours/days or you can use Google Cloud Messaging service.

GCM: Here is a link describing the usage of GCM with a PHP web server:

http://www.programming-techniques.com/2014/01/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-in-android.html

So if you have any update on your site this can notify GCM which will notify all registered users (their devices with your app running).

Comment: Do you know the difference between GCM and other services like Urban Airship?Does GCM do the same thing?

Comment: But can I connect GCM to my website?

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: Just for the record, Urban Airship uses GCM, it's essentially just a wrapper.